# How to delete a proposal at area51.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, support

I wanted to delete my stack exchange proposal at

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114485/modern-day-thinker.

I am getting more point deduction, so i want to delete it because i think i will hit negative scoring at this rate. Can some moderators delete it for me.

Comment: you can't drop below 1, if that is your concern.

Comment: Looks like you can't do that your self: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23174/are-proposals-deleted-or-closed-if-they-fail-the-5-question-5-follower-require but if you wait 5 days without anyone following your proposal it will be deleted automagically.

Comment: You can flag I think.